# Floating Action Button Snackbar with multi line

Tags: android, android-studio, floating-action-button, android-snackbar

When I click Action button Snack bar shows only two line of text and third line not showing

this is **XML** content

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_help" />
```

And I use this code in my activity

```
......
fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Hello word1" + "\n" + "Hello word2" + "\n" + "Hello word3", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
 .......
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually Android `Snackbar` have a `TextView` to show your text. So by setting Multi line in `TextView` you can achieve your target. Try this code, it worked for me.

```
 Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(Yourview, "Your Text", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
 View sbView = snackbar.getView();

 TextView textView =  sbView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);

 // For multi-line text, limit max line count.
 textView.setMaxLines(3);

 snackbar.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

**This code works for me**

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //....
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            showSnack(view, "My three line message", 5000);
        }
    });
     //....
}


public void showSnack(View view, String text, int duration) {
    snackbar = Snackbar.make(view, text, duration);
    View sbView = snackbar.getView();
    TextView textView = sbView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
    textView.setTextSize(16);
    textView.setMaxLines(3);
    snackbar.show();
}
```